# Change the values of a particular key in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x

I want to update the value of a particular key in the list of dictionaries.

For example I have the following list of dictionaries (Input values):

```
   deviceDynamics = [{'updated': '2019-07-10T10:27:44.763Z',
                  'created': '2019-07-10T10:27:44.763Z'},
                  {'updated': '2019-07-10T10:27:44.763Z',
                  'created': '2019-07-10T10:27:44.763Z'},
                  {'updated': '2019-07-10T10:27:44.763Z',
                  'created': '2019-07-10T10:27:44.763Z'}]
```

My code is -

```py
for d in deviceDynamics:
    timestamp = ((datetime.strptime(d['updated'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')) - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()


    d = next(d for d in deviceDynamics)
    d['updated'] = timestamp

    print(deviceDynamics)
```

Instead of changing the every `created` keys value it is changing the first one. The following is the output -

```
[{'created': '2019-07-10T10:27:44.763Z', 'updated': 1562754464.763}, {'created': '2019-07-10T10:27:44.763Z', 'updated': '2019-07-10T10:27:44.763Z'}, {'created': '2019-07-10T10:27:44.763Z', 'updated': '2019-07-10T10:27:44.763Z'}]
```

But it is not changing the other `created` keys value...any suggestion, please

Comment: `d = next(d for d in deviceDynamics)` is creating a new iterator and giving you the first item in it every time. Why don't you use the `d` you already had?

Comment: actually, I want to print the whole list of dictionaries with the modified values

Comment: How does that relate to the problem at hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the line where you are setting d equal to the new iterator that is always stuck on the first item.

```
for d in deviceDynamics:
    timestamp = ((datetime.strptime(d['updated'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')) -datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()

    d['updated'] = timestamp

    print(deviceDynamics)
```

If you would like to print the entire list with the updated KV pairs, include a print statement outside of your for loop.

```
for d in deviceDynamics:
    timestamp = ((datetime.strptime(d['updated'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')) - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()

    d['updated'] = timestamp

print(deviceDynamics)
```